# Accessing component state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am interested in understanding why setting a components state `(setState())` is slow to update i.e. I may read an old value after the fact that I called setState(). Additionally i am interested in knowing if reading the component state also incurs a penalty to know if I should minimize the number of reads/writes to component state. I tried looking for the documentation at the react website but no dice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` is asynchronous, so you won't get the new value in the same function where you update it